# How to import library in gDesklets applets?

Tags: python, import, applet

I want to use some math functions in a gDesklets applet, however, I can't `import math` in the script. I have googled but got nothing, except [this similar post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t398812-gdesklets-question-import-problem.html), yet unanswered.

I've tried to import at run time, but `__import__` doesn't work:

```
name '__import__' is not defined                                                     
/usr/lib/gdesklets/Displays/Clock/clock.display                                      
    1
    2 #
>   3 math = __import__('math')
```

and neither could `eval()` work:

```
name 'eval' is not defined                                                           
/usr/lib/gdesklets/Displays/Clock/clock.display                                      
    1
    2 #
>   3 math = eval('__import__("math")')
```

Comment: Uh.. Why vote to close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gDesklets is designed to be safe, so functions as import, eval, exec, etc., are disabled due to security reasons. To force enable these functions, you should change the source code:

```
/usr/lib/gdesklets/scripting/Script.py:

  ...
  self.__environment["str"] = str
  self.__environment["sum"] = sum
  ...
+ self.__environment["__import__"] = __import__
+ self.__environment["eval"] = eval
  ...
```

(+) Added these two lines, functions `__import__` and `eval` will then be available in the user scripts.